# Cannot specify 'title' from product table - php artisan tinker

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan, tinker

Using `php artisan tinker` I'm able to pull a product table that relates to, in this example, the first user in my database

```
>>> App\User::first()->product;
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2912
     all: [
       App\product {#2898
         id: 2,
         owner_id: 2,
         title: "ListingTestTitle",
         description: "ListingTestDescription",
         price: "420.69",
         created_at: "2019-11-08 13:21:28",
         updated_at: "2019-11-08 13:21:28",
       },
     ],
   }
```

However when I attempt to go into this collection further and just grab the title I get the following error

```
>>> App\User::first()->product->title;
Exception with message 'Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.'
```

I get the same issue no matter which attribute I attempt to pull.

Comment: As a sidenote, this is why correct variable naming is important. `product` is a singular noun, and should reflect a single instance, so having it return `hasMany()` in the form of a `Collection` is wrong. This relationship should be `products` if you want to use `hasMany()` and get multiple `Product` instances, or `product` if you want to use `hasOne()` or `belongsTo()` and get a single `Product` instance. Also, class names are `StudlyCase`, so `App\Product` instead of `App\product`.

Comment: I'll work on better naming conventions. Thanks a lot for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `product` is a `hasMany` relationship in your `User` model, access the first one as well from the relationship collection

```php
App\User::first()->product->first()->title;
```

Or just change the relationship to a `hasOne`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

*You can use `hasOne` relationship in your `User` Model*

```
App\User::first()->product->first()->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
App\User::first()->product->first()->title;
```

Comment: While this is correct, you should take a little time to explain *why* they should use this code.